# Prove that $f(x)=\frac x{e^x-1}$ for $x\neq 0$, $f(0)=1$, is $C^\infty$

Tags: limits, functions, derivatives, taylor-expansion

How to prove that $f : x \mapsto \frac{x}{\exp(x)-1}, \ x\neq 0$, and $1$ if $x=0$ is $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$.

For $x\neq 0$ , $f'(x)=\frac{\exp(x)-1-x\exp(x)}{(\exp(x)-1)^2}$, so we can extend $f'$ to $0$ taking : $f'(0)=-\frac{1}{2}$. Then we can conclude that $f \in \mathcal{C}^1(\mathbb{R})$.

Now maybe an induction could work but the calculation of the successive derivatives seems tricky.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: I guess there is a mistake in the function because it is not well defined at $x=1$.... maybe it is $f(x)=\frac{\exp(x)}{1-\exp(x)}$ ?

Comment: @DavidJaramillo Indeed it was a typo !

Answer (score 1):

A possible approach is the following. Consider the function $g=1/f$, and use the Taylor expansion of the exponential function. The remark the derivatives of $g$ at zero are never equal to zero, and conclude that $f$ is infinitely often differentiable at zero.

Comment: Can we use a Taylor expansion in a neighborhood of $0$ for $g$ ?

Comment: It is indeed possible, but I realize that my approach requires some basic knowledge of complex analysis.

Comment: Where I saw the statement there were two questions : prove that $f \in \mathcal{C}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ then prove that $f$ has a Taylor expansion in a neighborhood of $0$ (the convergence radius will be $\le 2\pi$ by the way)...

Answer (score 0):

HINT.-The limit of $f(x)$ when $x\to0$ exists and is in fact equal to $1$ so one can well define $f(0)=1$ **but** the second derivative of $f(x)$ is equal to
$$e^x\left(x+\frac{2}{(e^x-1)^3}\right)$$ and the limit of $\dfrac{2e^x}{(e^x-1)^3}$ does not exists for $x\to0$ (we have $-\infty$ when $x\to0^-$ and $+\infty$ when $x\to0^-$)

Comment: I found $f''(x)=\frac{\exp(x)(\exp(x)(x-2)+x+2)}{(\exp(x)-1)^3}$ and the extension would be $f''(0)=\frac{1}{6}$...

Comment: Verify your calculation, maybe I am wrong. Anyway $f$ is not $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ as you have proposed (I guess it is on $\mathbb R^+\setminus \{0\}$ but this is not important here).

Comment: According to the statement the first question is to prove that $f\in \mathcal{C}(\mathbb{R})$ then to prove that $f$ has a Taylor expansion in a neighborhood of $0$...